# Most efficient VBA code to convert string variable to integer 

Tags: string, excel, vba, optimization

I have the following code that converts a string of the following format:
`"G##"` to an integer `##`

```
Dim str As String
Dim int As Integer
str = "G14"
int = CInt(Right(str, Len(str) - 1))
```

But this is going to be run on a large database regularly.

I am wondering if there are any alternatives that may be more efficient (especially in regards to the last line)?

Comment: So when you ran in on a test database of similar size as the large database, how long did it take, where were the bottlenecks, and how much faster does it need to be?

Comment: The actual database query took the longest time. The whole operation takes a minute or so. The string parsing is really the only other thing that could be optimized; so, I figure if I can, I might as well.

Comment: So, how much of it was the query, and how much was the string parsing?  I have a feeling the query was like 1 minute and the string parsing was a couple seconds.  If that's the case, it's probably not worth optimizing this piece of code at the sacrifice of readability and simplicity of the code.

Comment: I'm just estimating, for time distribution, as I don't have any profiling tools available. But, I guess you're right; I suppose I'm just micro-optimizing and it doesn't really matter that much.

Comment: @Azmisov micro-optimizing, maybe, but that doesn't mean it's a bad thing. It doesn't hurt to ask for a better solution if one is out there, and it seems like Beaner just provided you with a more optimized version of your approach, which is pretty neat. I don't necessarilly agree that you need extreme performance testing like mellamokb is asking for just to get some opinions.

Comment: @Sam: Since when is actually testing your code in a realistic environment "extreme performance testing"?  How else would you test it?  How else can you know what to fix?  The reason why premature optimization is a problem is because you can spend hours solving the wrong problem, and end with more complicated code, nothing really improved, and lots of time/$$ wasted for your company.  Spending a little more time digging into the root of the performance issue *first* is IMHO time well invested.

Comment: @mellamokb Agreed, it's a crucial part of any realistic environment to discern the cause of poor performance. IMHO, however, gathering all that information is beyond the scope of this very simple question of "can this code be optimized", which Beaner was able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my testing using

```
 Mid$(strTest, 1, 1) = "0"
 lngTest = CLng(strTest)
```

was 30-40% faster then using

```
CLng(Right$(strTest, Len(strTest) - 1))
```

which in turn was signififcantly faster than

```
CLng(Right(strTest, Len(strTest) - 1))
```

*I used `Long` as it is superior speed wise to `Integer`*

For multiple replacements a `RegExp` may come into it's own. The overhead is too high to justify it for this sample

**Test Code**

```
Sub Test()
Dim dbTime As Double
Dim strTest As String
Dim lngTest As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long

strTest = "G14"

dbTime = Timer
For lngCnt = 1 To 1000000
lngTest = CLng(Right$(strTest, Len(strTest) - 1))
Next lngCnt
Debug.Print Timer - dbTime

dbTime = Timer
For lngCnt = 1 To 1000000
lngTest = CLng(Right(strTest, Len(strTest) - 1))
Next lngCnt
Debug.Print Timer - dbTimer


dbTime = Timer
For lngCnt = 1 To 1000000
Mid$(strTest, 1, 1) = "0"
lngTest = CLng(strTest)
Next lngCnt
Debug.Print Timer - dbTime
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code against int = CInt(Mid$(str, 2)) for 100,000,000 iterations and the Mid$ statement is slightly faster (6 seconds on my machine), but that was a lot of iterations. However when I added a **$** to your Right function they ran at the same speed. Using the string function `Right$` is better optimized for strings than the variant version `Right`. So the only suggestion I have to use the string optimized version Right$.

```
Dim str As String
Dim int As Integer
str = "G14"
int = CInt(Right$(str, Len(str) - 1))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is Val any faster or slower than CInt?

Comment: @GuitarPicker I tried it over the same 100,000,000 iterations and saw no appreciable difference.