# Is there a shorter way of appending information to an existing string?

Tags: string, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Is there a shorter way of appending information to an existing string in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) than:

```
strExample = strExample & "Lorem Ipsum"
```

I've got a lot of these when compiling dynamic strings, and it'd save time and look neater in my code if there was a shorter way of typing this.

Thanks

Comment: @rekire: you are actually right. Unfortunately, it's sometime cheaper to fix an existing app than rewriting the whole mess. This is a short term vision, but a field vision.

Comment: You can create a `cat strExample, "Lorem Ipsum", "more", ...` concatenation function. A substitution routine for constant strings can be useful too `format "aaa %1 bbb %2", var1, var2, ...`

Comment: There are a number of ways though to write more efficient string manipulations. For example a) concatenate long string & (short string & short string) rather than long string & short string & short string b)Use string functions `Left$` rather than the variant `Left` c) Use `Mid` on the left hand side for building strings, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095696/most-efficient-vba-code-to-convert-string-variable-to-integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sorry that **is not possible**.

With [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) you can use the operator `&=`.
But it is not available for [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript).

Comment: Question was on VBA - not vbscript. They are very different

Comment: @brettdj So is the `&=` operator aviable in VBA? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a global string var and create a function to add on to just that string. It wouldn't save that much time coding, but it may be something that helps

```
Public strExample as String

Sub Main()
   {do something}
   AddTo("One")
   {do something else}
   AddTo("Two")
End Sub

Sub AddTo(str as String)
   strExample = strExample & str
End Sub
```

Comment: I do something like this with special variables I use all the time like SQL statements I build on the fly.

Comment: Looks expensive to run a separate Sub for a simple concatenation.